# How to generate a sum and carry with Chisel in one line?

Tags: chisel

Is it possible to generate sum and carry in one line in Chisel similar to this code in Verilog?

```
  module Adder_with_carry(
  input [3:0] A,
  input [3:0] B,
     input Carry_in,
  output [3:0] Sum,
  output Carry_out
  );

    assign {Carry_out, Sum} = A + B + Carry_in;

  endmodule
```

I am using this code

```
  class Adder extends Module{
  val io = new Bundle{
  val a = UInt(INPUT, 3)
  val b = UInt(INPUT, 3)
  val carry_in = UInt (INPUT, 1)
  val sum = UInt (OUTPUT, 2)
  val carry_out = UInt(OUTPUT, 1)
    }

    val SUM = io.a + io.b + io.carry_in;

    io.carry_out := SUM(2) 
    io.sum := SUM(1,0)

  }
```

But I think it will be more convenient if there is a one-liner for this.